# Maya Python: Edit points in a Gradient Attribute Editor

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I have already build a script for getting a specific window, the string of the window is 'gradientAttributeEditor' and I would like to access the editor to create there some points by script. But I am not sure how.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def rampEditor():

    windows = cmds.lsUI(windows = True)
    for x in windows:
        if not x == "gradientAttributeEditor":
            windows.remove(x)
        else:
            editor = x

    print(windows)

rampEditor()
```

this puts the gradientAttributeEditor into x. But getting now the name to set some points, is kinda difficult for me :/

If some does not know how open the gradientAttributeEditor:
Create an object primitive, select it and under the FX Tab, go to the nParticle dropdown and click fill object. If you now select the particleShape and got to ParticleSize and lcik the little Arrow

[This is the gradientAttributeEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Alje.jpg)

Comment: I am unsure what you're asking; do you want to create control points in the gradient editor, or do you want to create "particles", as it seems from @Achayan's answer?

Comment: I want a script that is looking for an open gradientEditor and by a button click it makes an exponantial curve. The problem is that I do not know how to get access to the editor.
The script should be kept as universal as possible, so not only working for particleSize or wahtever, more for the gradientEditor that is open right now.
I hope it clears some things up.

Answer (score 1):

For creating point you really don't need to use the window I think .. just use command itself ?

for example :

```
MC.setAttr("nParticleShape1.radiusScale[0].radiusScale_Position", 0.122)
MC.setAttr("nParticleShape1.radiusScale[0].radiusScale_FloatValue", 0.460)

MC.setAttr("nParticleShape1.radiusScale[1].radiusScale_Position", 0.5)
MC.setAttr("nParticleShape1.radiusScale[1].radiusScale_FloatValue", 0.1)
```